# cakephp 2.0 features?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

where can i read more about cakephp 2.0 features?

cause i could find symfony 2.0 presentations but not for cakephp 2.0

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CakePHP 2.x](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/home). There are links to the migration guide and development roadmap at the right there.
Update: [development roadmap](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/2-0-development-roadmap), [migration guide](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/2-0-migration-guide).

Comment: Something about cakephp2 and cakephp3 - http://debuggable.com/posts/Cake_3_interview_with_Nate_Abele:4a665a5e-5bfc-4e42-96ee-6d284834cda3

Comment: @bancer that's quite outdated now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy site for Cakephp 2.0 documentation. It compiles the rst files from the above mentioned github.com/cakephp/docs into the familiar cookbook format.

[CakeDocs.com](http://www.cakedocs.com)

Comment: That is not the correct book link, it is actually part of a scam, the correct link is  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en

Comment: That was not part of a scam. That was used before cake was updating the manual for 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A summary is here:

http://www.slideshare.net/markstory/ch-chchanges-cake-php2

Answer (score 0):

The main changes, compared with the 1.3 branch, can be found here:

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/20-new-features